# Getting CORS error on uploading file using Google Cloud Storage signed request

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am using fetch on client side to upload an image file.

```
const uploadResponse = await fetch(response.signedURL, {
    method: 'PUT',
    mode: 'cors',
    body: selectedFile,
    credentials: 'omit',
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
    }
});
```

Configured my storage bucket using following config

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["https://zipsym.eu.loclx.io"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type","Access-Control-Allow-Origin"],
      "method": ["PUT"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

But still I am getting the following error
[image]

These are my response headers
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you configured the storage bucket with the listed config, did the request succeed?

Comment: I configured using gsutils command 'gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://recoverlution-dev' and I didnt get any error on console. Is there any way to verify whether it is configured or not.

Comment: It is possible that client side caching is happening in the browser here and the bucket metadata was cached without headers. If you disable browser caching does this issue still occur? It's also possible that fetch could be causing a signedURL issue that isn't being returned. If you use cURL, does the issue persist?